# Designing filters for solr

Tags: solr, filter

Can anybody suggest me a reference guide for designing special filters for solr?
I am going to design filters based on special algorithms for arabic language so that my filter should support unicode.
 thanks in advance.
best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably find a [TokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenFilter.html) which does something that looks like what you are trying to do (but for a different language for example) and find its code on [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.5.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenFilter.java#TokenFilter) to understand how it works.